# Android controlling other apps

Tags: android, mobile

I was wondering if there was a way in android to be able to create an app to invoke events such as on touch in other apps. I wanted to have a floating app that could run over other apps and I could invoke touch events on the main running app. If you have any ideas on how to do this without root that would be wonderful.

One idea I had is emulated the main app within my app then controlling the touch events but I'm not sure if that will work.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can pass certain information to the other apps which is allowed by it. Like launch youtube and play video from your app. But you cannot search terms on youtube app without using youtube.

For other apps you should be having their apis. Only methods allowed through the api can be done.